# Visual C++ 2013 & error C2065: 'complex' : undeclared identifier & error C2059: syntax error : ','

Tags: c++

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include "math.h"
    #include <complex>
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "conio.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include <io.h>
    void multiple(complex**,complex*,complex*);
    void solve(complex**, complex*, complex*, int);
```

As I typed the above-mentioned code, we receive the following errors:
error C2065: 'complex' : undeclared identifier
error C2059: syntax error : ','
Many thanks for your time,

Comment: `complex` is C, and is in header `<complex.h>`. The header `<complex>` gives you the C++ class template [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I tried it, but still program could not even find complex* while I am typing it!!!!!

Comment: Tried what? You haven't even said which of the two approaches you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The class is located in the namespace `std` as well as all other C++ standard library classes / functions. So you have to change `complex` to `std::complex<T>` (don't forget the template parameter!).

Comment: How do you know OP wants `std::complex`?

Comment: @juanchopanza The question is tagged with C++, therefore I thought so.